# How do I finish this ai?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
from random import*
from numpy import array


input_randoms = []
for i in range(10000):
    input_randoms.append([randint(0,100),randint(0,100)])
output_randoms = []
for pair in input_randoms:
    output_randoms.append(sum(pair))


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(202, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(array(input_randoms), output_randoms, epochs=5)

model.evaluate([[50,32],[16,18]],  [82,34], verbose=2)
```

Output is:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
Train on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 107us/sample - loss: 7.1288 - acc: 0.0090
Epoch 2/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 69us/sample - loss: 4.9724 - acc: 0.0120
Epoch 3/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 67us/sample - loss: 4.8243 - acc: 0.0132
Epoch 4/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 68us/sample - loss: 4.7343 - acc: 0.0113
Epoch 5/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 69us/sample - loss: 4.6702 - acc: 0.0139
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4b4fc1f78d7e> in <module>()
     26 model.fit(array(input_randoms), output_randoms, epochs=5)
     27 
---> 28 model.evaluate([[50,32],[16,18]],  [82,34], verbose=2)
     29 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    570                              ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    571                              str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 572                              str(data_shape))
    573   return data
    574 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I am trying to finish this ai.

As far as I understand, model.evaluate([[50,32],[16,18]],  [82,34], verbose=2) I should put two sample inputs and correct answer to them. Output which I am looking for is as presented above in Output before error.

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this? What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have missed a pair of brackets, once I add the brackets, the input should be correct. I am also a beginner and don't know much...

```
model.evaluate([[50,32],[16,18]],  [82,34], verbose=2)
```

to

```
model.evaluate([[[50,32],[16,18]]],  [82,34], verbose=2)
```

[image: screenshot of my testing]